# How do iterate through tuple functions following a certain condition

Tags: python

I would like to iterate through a tuple following certain conditions such as follows.
I have defined a variable L = []. I have several functions imported into a tuple and I would like, that if this condition is met, while iterating through the tuple, the function that meets this condition will print out an answer. I have worked out this code but cant seen to get the correct way. Am not a professional python guru and I welcome any critics.

```
L = []
def one():    
    L = 1*2    
    print '1 yea!'
    return L

def two():
    L = 1+2    
    print '2 yea!'
    return L

def three():
    L = 1/2    
    print ' 3 yea!'
    return L

def four ():
    L = 1-2    
    print '4 yea!'
    return L

refined = (one, two, three, four)

def these():
    for x in refined:
        b1 = iter(refined)
        if L ==2:
            return b1
        else:
            print 'nothing here'
```

Comment: Please clarify. What is the exact output you would like to see?

Comment: What precisely is the point of `b1 = iter(refined)`, given that 1. you're already iterating over `refined` and 2. you never use `b1`? It is not at all clear what you were expecting would happen.

Comment: Edited. I what , that if the condition L ==2 is met e.g. by def one(), the the only string to be printed out is '1 yea!' and not all strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

```
def one():    
    L = 1*2    
    print '1 yea!'
    return L

def two():
    L = 1+2    
    print '2 yea!'
    return L

def three():
    L = 1/2    
    print ' 3 yea!'
    return L

def four ():
    L = 1-2    
    print '4 yea!'
    return L

refined = (one, two, three, four)

def these(refined, L):
    return refined[L]

for L in range(4):
    print these(refined, L)()
```

EDIT: for 1 particular value:

```
print these(refined, 2)()
```

Run it and get:

```
$ python refined.py
1 yea!
2
2 yea!
3
 3 yea!
0
4 yea!
-1
```

Comment: You are confused with how to use iterators.  In my code, these() takes the tuple, and the index, and returns the value at that index.  Since this is a function, in the bottom test loop i add () to it to actually call the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I how ever want it to print only one string that meets a condition such as, if L ==2. I how ever will work with this. Kind regards!

Comment: I added to bottom of my answer for picking one function only